# Validation with ASP.NET MVC Linq To SQL: how do I avoid editing a generated source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, decorator

I'm reading several docs on validation in `ASP.NET MVC`. Ignoring those that suggest to reinvent the wheel writing your own validation logic, most articles advocate the use of `xVal` or Data Annotation Validators, both of which allow declarative validation through decorating models' properties(*).

I think I'll go for `xVal`, as it seems to be the most suggested (and thus, I hope, supported). What puzzles me is that I'm using `Linq to SQL`, and my models are declared in an automatically generated file (`dbml` + `partial.cs`), containing several classes and almost 5000 lines long, so I'm not very eager to edit it, as if I change the db structure I'll have to regenerate it, loosing my changes.

Is there a way to avoid editing that file?

---

(*) I've also found a [Validator Toolkit](http://mvcvalidatortoolkit.codeplex.com/) which also provides declarative validation and doesn't request to decorate models' properties, but the page shows 57 downloads, so I can't tell if the project is mature or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a partial class and add the Data Annotation Validators to the partial class that way it doesn't matter if your dbml file is regenerated.

Try this [asp.net article](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx) and [this article](http://rachelappel.com/asp-net-dynamic-data/custom-validation-in-asp-net-dynamic-data-using-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [buddy classes](http://goneale.com/2009/03/04/using-metadatatype-attribute-with-aspnet-mvc-xval-validation-framework/) -- really the only way to fly with generated models and DataAnnotation-based validation.

Comment: yes, it's the same solution suggested in the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can (xVal). [See here](http://rachelappel.com/asp-net-dynamic-data/custom-validation-and-business-logic-in-asp-net-dynamic-data-using-partial-methods/) and [here](http://rachelappel.com/asp-net-dynamic-data/custom-validation-in-asp-net-dynamic-data-using-attributes/).