# ASP.NET MVC validation - LINQ to SQL and view models - a little help on proper flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, validation, model, view

I'm trying to grasp my head around the best way to carry out something.

I'm creating a very simple forum, using ASP.NET MVC and LINQ to SQL. Very simple means it has no categories, and each message consists of a subject, a composer and the message contents. Comments can be threaded, but only go one level deep (if you comment on a child message, it will appear as though you commented on the parent message of that child).

Oh, I also properly paginated the forum.

Now, the ASP.NET MVC flow bit I'm trying to understand:

When someone goes to `Home/Forum/{page}` I create a model for the view with 2 objects - a list of all the messages to show (in the proper order of parents and children. I create the list server-side), and a `forumMessage newMessage` object, so if the user creates a new message, or replies to an existing message, I can easily populate the object and send it back to the server.

However, after reading **lots** of articles on validation, models, etc., it seems to me as though I would be better off using broken-down message fields to be filled out by the user (i.e: `String messageComposer; String messageComposer; String messageContents;`), since it will be easier to define validation rules for them.

This is for two reasons:

1) since the `forumMessage` object is created using LINQ to SQL, it's kinda of an issue to define its validation rules (yes, I know you can use [buddy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420136/validation-with-asp-net-mvc-linq-to-sql-how-do-i-avoid-editing-a-generated-sourc), but I'm kinda scared O_o )

and what seems to be the bigger reason 2) in all validation examples, if the data that was needed to be validated was passed as an object (i.e `forumMessage`), then it was the only object in the model. I saw no reference to scenarios in which the model consisted of data which was also used simply to populate the views (in my case - the forum messages for the particular page).

### Which brings me to this:

**So far, whenever I had to get input from the user, I passed along the objects which I wanted to display or populate as the actual LINQ to SQL objects.**

**Was I going about this the wrong way? Should I pass LINQ to SQL objects (i.e. classes) for display purposes, but use plain old fields (strings, ints, etc.) for the data I want to retrieve, and create the actual LING to SQL object server side, when I get all the data back to the controller?**

I'm at a crossroads here, and would appreciate some help from seasoned veterans :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm creating a very simple forum

As it's a simple forum, then the simplest approach would be best, i.e. using Linq-2-Sql object through the entire process (i.e from DAL to View)

Regarding using a mix of objects/properties, I would use a separate ViewModel to aggregate the data.

e.g.

```
// class used for the strongly typed view
public class ForumMessageViewModel
{
   // linq-2-sql class
   public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }

   // contains data that you want to get back
   public NewMessage NewMessage  { get; set; }
}

// represents a new message
public class NewMessage
{
    [StringLength(100)]
    string MessageComposer { get; set ;}
}
```

Your View (cut down, simplistic version)

```
@model ForumMessageViewModel

<!-- render the messages -->

...

<!-- entry for new message -->

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMessage", "ForumController"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewMessage.MessageComposer)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewMessage.MessageComposer)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewMessage.MessageComposer)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit new message" />
    </p>    
}
```

You can then use a Binding Prefix on your controller ...

```
public ViewResult AddMessage([Bind(Prefix="NewMessage")] NewMessage newmessage)
{
    // logic to save 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's a "Binding Prefix"? :-P

Comment: The alternative would be  - public ViewResult AddMessage(ForumMessageViewModel model).  It allows you to filter the properties on your ViewModel making the definition clearer.